# Как установить курсор перед найденным словом?

Tags: c#, поиск, richtextbox

Как в richTextBox установить курсор перед найденным словом?
Хочу сделать поиск с кнопкой "Найти далее...".
Пока есть выделение совпадений.

```
if (txtB_Find.Text.Length > 0)
    {
          int indexToText = rTB_Result.Find(txtB_Find.Text);

          if (indexToText >= 0)
          {
                int i = 0;
                MatchCollection allIp = Regex.Matches(rTB_Result.Text, txtB_Find.Text);
                foreach (Match ip in allIp)
                {
                      rTB_Result.SelectionStart = ip.Index;
                      rTB_Result.SelectionLength = ip.Length;
                      rTB_Result.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 160, 122);
                      i = i + 1;
                 } 
                 MessageBox.Show("Найдено совпадений: " + i, txtB_Find.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Искомый элемент НЕ найден!", txtB_Find.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
      }
```

Comment: Установить `rTB_Result.SelectionLength = 0` вместо `ip.Length`

Comment: @nick_n_a если я меняю на rTB_Result.SelectionLength = 0; то у меня не выделяется искомый текст. Курсор не появляется.

Comment: Наверно нужно `richTextBox.SelectionStart = позиция`, и Length там же потому как rTB_Result не совсем понятно что.

Comment: @nick_n_a а как узнать позицию?

Comment: Я вам в ответе показал.

Answer (score 0):

Заменить `rTB_Result.SelectionLength = ip.Length;` на `rTB_Result.SelectionLength = 0;` если нужно установить курсор.

Хотя, по хорошему я бы ещё сделал бы цикл поиска так

```
bool ipcatch = false;
int ipsel = -1;
foreach (Match ip in allIp){
  if (ipsel < 0 )  ipsel =ip.Index;
  if (ipcatch) {
      ipsel =ip.Index;
      ipcatch = false;
      };
 if (rTB_Result.SelectionStart == ip.Index)  ipcatch = true;
 i=i+1;
 rTB_Result.SelectionStart = ip.Index;
 rTB_Result.SelectionLength = ip.Length;
 rTB_Result.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 160, 122);
 }
 if (ipsel >=0 ) {
     richTextBox.SelectionStart = ipsel;
     richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
```